# What is the difference between the original Apple watch, and the 2016 announcement of "Series 1"

Tags: apple-watch

As of the latest announcement in 2016, there appears to be 3 types of Apple watches

- Original (Series 0?)
- Series 1
- Series 2

What isn't clear is the distinction between the original Apple watch and Series 1.

Prior to the announcement, the original Apple Watch (Series 0) listed at $349. Then it was discounted to $249.

```
Part numbers of Series 0:

- MJ3T2LL/A MJ2X2LL/A (Black)
- MJ3R2LL/A MJ2W2LL/A (red)
- MJ3P2LL/A MJ2P2LL/A (green)
- MJ3T2LL/A MJ2T2LL/A (silver)
- MLC42LL/A MLCF2LL/A (Orange)
- MLC52LL/A MLCG2LL/A (Silver)
- MLCH2LL/A (Rose Gold)
- MLC62LL/A MLCJ2LL/A
- MLC72LL/A (Gold + midnight blue)
```

From what I can tell, the original Apple Watch has these differences from Apple Watch "Series 1"

```
      Series "0"   Series 1
Cost    $249         $269
CPU    1 core?      2 core
         both are Splash resistant
         both have Wifi b/g/n
         both have bluetooth 4.0
         both have a heart rate sensor
          ???       accelerometer
          ???       gyroscope
          ???       ambient light sensor
```

Comment: Probably the CPU change is the only difference.

Answer (score 2):

The Apple Watch Series 1 has all the same features that shipped with the original Apple Watch. The only differences are that Series 1 models:

- include the new dual-core processor
- come pre-installed with watchOS 3.